# ASP.NET MVC How to validate a posted value comes from a list

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, data-annotations

I have a drop down list on a form. A malicious user could arrange to post a value that isn't on the list.

A sample view model would be:

```
public class CountryViewModel {
    [Required]
    public int CountryId { get; set; }
    public IList<Country> CountryList { get; set; }
}
```

`CountryId` will be posted, `CountryList` will be populated at the start of the relevant controller before `Model.IsValid` is called. When `Model.IsValid` is called, I'd like an error if there is no Country in the list with a matching `CountryId`. The country list comes from a database, so an enum won't work.

I can solve this using `IValidateableObject` or `CustomValidationAttribute`, but is there a built in way in Data Annotations?

Comment: You would have to add a condition in your post method that looks up the data and checks if it's in the list, if not add an error to the Model errors and return back.  DataAnnotations are compile-time attributes though, so even if there was a way, it would be static and not database driven.  IValidatableObject isn't a bad choice either.